# python Flask RuntimeError: Working outside of request context

Tags: python, celery

I looked at all related questions but could not found what I want for.
I have a flask app `app.py` that also includes celery task in it

```
from flask import Flask, request, current_app
from celery import Celery
from mongoalchemy.session import Session
from PIL import Image
from model import the_data

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

celery = Celery('app', broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

@celery.task
def process_image():
    with app.app_context():
        session = Session.connect('mydb')
        session.clear_collection(the_data)
        image = Image.open(request.files['file'])
        ### do something ###

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' in request.files:
            process_image.delay()
    return 'Processing image...'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8008)
```

In short, `app.py` will receive an image file sent via `requests.post` from other script and pass it to queue for processing using celery.

I use `app.app_context()` as what I found out to be the solution for the `RuntimeError: Working outside of request context` but unfortunately even after I edited my code, the error still there.

What should I do to solve this type of error?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

It [looks like](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay) you can pass *args and **kwargs to your task by including them as arguments in you `delay` call. Pass the file to your `process_image` function. The reason this doesn't work is that you're accessing request outside of the context. Once `return 'Processing image...'` executes that context is closed.

**EDIT:** Basically, it appears from the documentation that I linked to that you can add an argument to your `process_image` function and pass it to it in the `delay` call. This is untested, so it may take some tweaking.

```
@celery.task
def process_image(file=None):        
    if file is None:
        return False
    image = Image.open(file)
        ### do something ###

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' in request.files:
            process_image.delay(request.files['file'])
    return 'Processing image...'
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but could you perhaps write an example of code of what you are thinking? I'm sorry because I did not really understand what you explain in your answer without any example. Thank you

Comment: using `**kwargs` is not good solution. Other developers will not see signature of function.

Comment: I was writing this a teaching experience, not production ready code. But if you insist, I'll update it.